# Excel formula apply conditions to all sheets same whole column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openoffice-calc

This question can be viewed as several small ones , but the main aim is one and only .

**TL;DR;**

I would like to apply an excel formula at sheet N , that will take into consideration all the corresponding columns, in full, in all the other sheets, while applying some conditions that are the same for all columns .

**Details :**

My spreadsheet is a very simple and basic expenses accounting , which has many sheets by years and dates named `2015.04`, `2015.05`, `2015.06` etc.
First row is always title ( time, date, amount , project, category etc. ) and the columns are always corresponding ( for example in all sheets column `H` will be category and `D` will be amount )

The starting formula is :

```
    =SUMIF('2015.07'.H2:H67;C20;'2015.07'.D2:D67)
// C20 is only a search condition like "travel", or "F&B"
```

And it works at this simplified manual mode , but since we have computers, and I have a programmers M.O, I want to automate it a bit , and hence my problems :

1 - How to apply this formula to all sheets , even if some are later added / deleted , e.g. the equivalent of "sheet wildcard "

```
 =SUMIF('*'.H2:H67;C20;'*'.D2:D67) // all sheets
```

or

```
=SUMIF('2015*'.H2:H67;C20;'2015*'.D2:D67) // all year
```

2 - Since the columns are not the same length , it is seems stupid to apply manual range , so I tried

```
  =SUMIF('2015.07'.H:H;C20;'2015.07'.D:D)
```

But it gives me several different errors .

3 - ONE of the errors I can understand, and that is that the first row TITLE is not a number , so I tried

```
=SUMIF('2015.07'.H1:H67;C20;ISNUMBER('2015.07'.D1:D99) )// err 504
```

and also tried

```
=SUMIF('2015.07'.H1:H67;C20;IF(ISNUMBER('2015.07'.D1:D99) ))// err 509
```

and

```
=SUMIF('2015.07'.H1:H67;C20;sum(IF(ISNUMBER('2015.07'.D1:D99)) ))// err 508
```

Now, I know I can take the simple working starting formula , put it in every single page, select the exact range without title, and then at the last summery page reference all the others - but seriously, I could also use an `ABACUS` , this is not why tools like excel were invented . or am I presuming too much of this tool ? is it that primitive ? I somehow refuse to believe it and just blame myself for not knowing it as well as I should .

I also know I can write a `VBA` macro, but at this point, it would take me much less effort and time to take [some PHP excel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library write some  PHP lines , dump all in SQL and do it right . But again - is it my fault ( probably ) or excel's ??

P.S>. Using OpenOffice Calc if that matters , but tried all also in excel with change of syntax and different error codes .

**EDIT I - SOLUTION**

After looking @Axel Richards answer, even if it not exactly helps me to resolve the problem, it did help me a lot in finding the way .

First, I found out that the errors I had were due to the naming of the sheets themselves . 
Apparently , a name like `2005.07` ( a dot ) will give `err 501` and `2005-07` ( hyphen ) will give `err 502`.  That made me understand that some of my earlier attempt were actually right - but the naming scheme created the errors .

so the final formula, which works for me is .
note that this is an array formula, and therefor needs to be entered with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` and not just `ENTER` , which produces the curly brackets ( I did not know that before .. )

```
{=SUMIF((INDIRECT("20150"&COLUMN(C$1:I$1)&".H"&ROW(A$1:A$500)));$J16;INDIRECT("20150"&COLUMN(C$1:I$1)&".D"&ROW(A$1:A$500)))}
```

The fact that there are no wildcard, is only half correct, because the solution would be to define a starting period, and end period, and the formula will calculate all of thee sheets in the middle . That is some kind of a wildcard for my purposes.

like so:

```
{=SUMIF((INDIRECT("start"&".H"&ROW(A$1:A$500)));$J16;INDIRECT("END"&".D"&ROW(A$1:A$500)))}
```

The use of `COLUMN(C$1:I$1)` is actually to create an array ( 3-9 ) and the `ROW(A$1:A$500)` tells thee formula to take into account everything for 500 rows .

This is hardly a flexible or elegant solution, but it works .

Comment: One way to do it is to write a small macro that checks all available sheets in your workbook and then updates the formula to include all of them. So if someone adds a new sheet later, the macro will detect it and will update the formula for your once it is run manually, or while the workbook is being loaded

Comment: @Ahmad Ok, but what about the formula itself ? how to selevt a whole column and verify the conditions ( ISNUMBER and C20 in example )

Comment: @Jerry - even if in the question the range copied is wrong ( should be `D2:D67` - thanks corrected now ) it still should work, the condition say in human language `sum from D2 to D67 only if you find the string C20 inside H2 to H67` so if the range is `D2:D6` it should sum only that range  ( regardless of the fact that it would be wrong for my calculations :-)  or not ? also - that is the point of the question - how to apply that to whole column regardless of its length ..

Comment: Ok, now that this is fixed, I'll first say that (as far as I know) there are no functions that can give you the list of worksheets in a file, nor a function that adapts to adding/deleting worksheets. The second issue can be addressed by using `SUMPRODUCT` to get the conditions. Your formula would become `=SUMPRODUCT(('2015.07'.H1:H67=C20)*IF(ISNUMBER('2015.07'.D1:D97),'2015.07'.D1:D97,0))`.

Comment: @Jerry ,thanks for taking time for this issue . The above still gives me error , and even if it wouldn`t  - it does not resolve the `D:D` vs. `Dx:Dn` problem.  If that is the case, I guess I just will have to manually do everything

Comment: I guess OpenCalc doesn't have sumproduct =/ The alternative would be array invocation of SUM: `=SUM(('2015.07'.H:H=C20)*IF(ISNUMBER('2015.07'.D:D),'2015.07'.D:D‌​,0))` (if you want full range)

Comment: @Jerry thanks, i will try this solution . But I guess it will not really help much if I can not automate this process .. If I need to copy and paste and adjust formulas on 100 sheets - it will take me less time do that analysis  in PHP , or Java , Or C++ or any other language like I wrote in Original question . :-) I guess excel can be really improved with a simple scripting language ...

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Indeed. If you have the ability to use them, I'd say go for it.

Comment: @AxelRichter - ( a bit offended - but..)  yes I am interested in a solution, and if you will read attentively I wrote myself  that I do Lack in knowledge of the tool hence my question here. regarding the data  In OP i already wrote that `C20` is only a search condition ( see the first formula remark .. ) . and it is not a sheet it is a cell . If you have a working formula to address the listed problems I will be glad to test and apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try an answering your questions.

1. Sheet wildcards

This is not possible. Why? Because the sheet name within `'2015.07'.H2:H67` is not simply a String but a reference. If you change the sheet name from "2015.07" in "whatever" then all those references in all formulas which are referencing this sheet will change.

2. Referencing whole columns and/or whole rows

This is not possible in Openoffice (Libreoffice). In Excel `=SUMIF('2015.07'!H:H,C20,'2015.07'!D:D)` will work. In Openoffice we have to reference the first cell and the last cell `=SUMIF($H$1:$H$1048576,C20,$D$1:$D$1048576)`.

Btw.: The error if you try `=SUMIF('2015.07'.H:H;C20;'2015.07'.D:D)` in Openoffice should be `#NAME?` because H and D are not defined names. This has nothing to do with being something not a number or not. `SUMIF` can deal with not numeric content in its sum range excepting with error values there.

3. Meanings of the error codes

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Error_Codes_in_Calc

So what I would do:

Assume the following example (in my Libreoffice is comma the formula parameter delimiter):

[image]

As you see the formula in `K2` is

```
=SUMIF($H$1:$H$1048576,$J2,$D$1:$D$1048576)
```

The formula in `J2` is

```
=$'Sheet N'.$C$20
```

This is a reference to "Sheet N" cell C20.

The Sheet N looks like:

[image]

The Formula in `D20` is

```
=SUM(Begin.K2:End.K2)
```

This is a 3D-reference. All cells `K2` in all sheets from sheet "Begin" till sheet "End" will be summed.

The sheets "Begin" and "End" are simply empty sheets.

Now you can copy the sheet "2015.01" as often as you want and place the copies between the sheets "Begin" and "End". You can change the content of the copied sheets according the new months. As long as in all copies is `J2` a reference to `=$'Sheet N'.$C20` and in `K2` is the `SUMIF` formula, then `D20` in "Sheet N" will be the sum of all those `SUMIF`s which will be dependent of `C20` in "Sheet N".

But at last to your mention:

> I also know I can write a VBA macro, but at this point, it would take
>   me much less effort and time to take some PHP excel library write some
>   PHP lines , dump all in SQL and do it right.

You are right with the hint to SQL. But also in SQL you would not have a own table each month and then taking a `UNION` of all those tables. You would have all expenses accounting in one table with the month as a field. If so also in the Spreadsheet, then `SUMIF` would be easy, wouldn't it?

And to the macro question:

No, because PHP could only put a long `=SUMIF...+SUMIF...+SUMIF...` formula into a cell. With VBA or Starbasic you could have a UDF (User Defined Function). This is much more flexible.

Example Openoffice Libreoffice

```
Public Function SUMIFOS(sSheetName as String, lColSearch as Long, vSearchValue as Variant, lColSum as Long) as Variant

  oDoc = Thiscomponent
  sFormula = ""
  vResult = 0

  oTextSearch = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.util.TextSearch")
  oOptions = CreateUnoStruct("com.sun.star.util.SearchOptions")
  oOptions.algorithmType = com.sun.star.util.SearchAlgorithms.REGEXP
  oOptions.searchString = sSheetName
  oTextSearch.setOptions(oOptions)

  For Each oSheet in oDoc.Sheets
   oFound = oTextSearch.searchForward(oSheet.Name, 0, Len(oSheet.Name)) 
   If  oFound.subRegExpressions <> 0 then

    sPath = ThisComponent.URL
    sSearchColumn = oSheet.Columns(lColSearch-1).AbsoluteName  
    sSumColumn = oSheet.Columns(lColSum-1).AbsoluteName  
    sSearchColumn = "'" & sPath & "'#" & sSearchColumn
    sSumColumn = "'" & sPath & "'#" & sSumColumn

    sFormula = "=SUMIF(" & sSearchColumn & ";""" & vSearchValue & """;" & sSumColumn & ")"

    oDocTMP = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.SpreadsheetDocument")

    oSheetTMP = oDocTMP.createInstance("com.sun.star.sheet.Spreadsheet")
    oDocTMP.Sheets.insertByName("MySheet", oSheetTMP)
    oRangeTMP = oSheetTMP.getCellRangeByName("A1")
    oRangeTMP.Formula = sFormula    

    vResult = vResult + oRangeTMP.Value

    oDocTMP = Nothing
    oSheetTMP = Nothing
    oRangeTMP = Nothing

   End If
  Next  

  SUMIFOS = vResult

End Function
```

Example VBA

```
Public Function SUMIFOS(sSheetName As String, lColSearch As Long, vSearchValue As Variant, lColSum As Long) As Variant

  Set oWB = ThisWorkbook

  vResult = 0

  Set oRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  oRegExp.Pattern = sSheetName

  For Each oSheet In oWB.Sheets
   If oRegExp.test(oSheet.Name) Then
    Set rSearchColumn = oSheet.Columns(lColSearch)
    Set rSumColumn = oSheet.Columns(lColSum)

    vResult = vResult + WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rSearchColumn, vSearchValue, rSumColumn)

   End If
  Next

  SUMIFOS = vResult

End Function
```

Usage as a Formula:

```
=SUMIFOS("2015.0[1,4]",8,C20,4)
```

Sum column 4 of sheets where names matching "2015.0[1,4]" if column 8 contains the value of `C20`.

Comment: I have accepted your answer because it pointed me in the right direction. read my edit .

Comment: Your first array formula works. But it works also as `{=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'2015.0"&COLUMN($A$1:$I$1)&"'.H"&ROW($A$1:$A$500));$C20;INDIRECT("'2015.0"&COLUMN($A$1:$I$1)&"'.D"&ROW($A$1:$A$500)))}` if the sheet names are `2015.01 ... 2015.09`. Note that I've wrapped the sheet names in single quotes within the references. So your presumption that such sheet names will always lead to errors is wrong. Also have you counted the seconds this array formula takes to get the result? Not really a solution in my opinion.

Comment: 1- well - I did not `presumed` that these names will `always` produce errors. I just said they did for me ( with my settings / sw/os versions ) .2 -  I did not count any second , because it is fractions .  ( The real work was already made in PHP / MySQL in 20 minutes. I just took this opportunity to learn some Excel / Calc functions despite your insinuating that the question was just for `bashing` excel.) ..TBC

Comment: 4 - I really do not understand why you specify that it is `not a solution`. you might argue that it is a `slow solution` , or not elegant like i wrote myself - but it is one for my needs and the one specified in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Give this code a shot:

```
Sub CreateSumIfFormulaForAllSheets()
  Tmp = ""
  For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Tmp = Tmp & IIf(Tmp = "", "=SUMIF('" & Sheets(i).Name & "'!H:H,C20,D:D)", "+SUMIF('" & Sheets(i).Name & "'!H:H,C20,D:D)")
  Next i
Range("A1").Formula = Tmp
End Sub
```

Assuming you're trying to get a single sum of all values in column D on all sheets where C20 is in column H on all sheets, this will work.  Just change "A1" to whatever cell your formula would normally be in.  And unless there are error values in your columns D, you won't have to worry about ISNUMBER because SUMIF ignores text.

If you actually need to define those column ranges (like H2:H67), rather than just looking at the whole column, you'll need to specify what criteria you would use to make that determination before it can be encoded into this macro.  You did say "whole column", and this will definitely look at the whole column.